# JSR223 Post Processor with java-script to pass a value to an array

Tags: jmeter, extract

This is response output from a request in jmeter,

```
{
    "item": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "American Samoa",
            "capital": "Pago Pago",
            "region": "Oceania",
            "subregion": "Polynesia",
            "population": 57100,
            "area": 199,
            "numericCode": "016"
        },
        {
            "id": 249,
            "name": "Zimbabwe",
            "capital": "Harare",
            "region": "Africa",
            "subregion": "Eastern Africa",
            "population": 14240168,
            "area": 390757,
            "numericCode": "716"
        },
        {
            "id": 250,
            "name": "Aland Islands",
            "capital": "Mariehamn",
            "region": "Europe",
            "subregion": "Northern Europe",
            "population": 28875,
            "area": 1580,
            "numericCode": "248"
        },
        {
            "id": 256,
            "name": "Test Name",
            "capital": "Capital",
            "region": "NF",
            "subregion": "LoadTesting",
            "population": 10,
            "area": 10,
            "numericCode": "9"
        },
        {
            "id": 257,
            "name": "Test Name",
            "capital": "Capital",
            "region": "NF",
            "subregion": "LoadTesting",
            "population": 10,
            "area": 10,
            "numericCode": "9"
        },
        {
            "id": 258,
            "name": "Test Name",
            "capital": "Capital",
            "region": "NF",
            "subregion": "LoadTesting",
            "population": 10,
            "area": 10,
            "numericCode": "9"
        },
        {
            "id": 259,
            "name": "Test Name",
            "capital": "Capital",
            "region": "NF",
            "subregion": "LoadTesting",
            "population": 10,
            "area": 10,
            "numericCode": "9"
        },
        {
            "id": 260,
            "name": "Test Name",
            "capital": "Capital",
            "region": "NF",
            "subregion": "LoadTesting",
            "population": 10,
            "area": 10,
            "numericCode": "9"
        }
    ],
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

The output is in the JSON format, and I want to retrieve all the id which have "name": "Test Name","capital": "Capital","region": "NF","subregion": "LoadTesting" and store them in an array.

I am using jmeter 5.2, with JSR223 post-processor with javascript. I am getting error with the following script.

```
var responseData = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
var countryDetails = responseData.Items;


log.info(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
log.info(countryDetails);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) also, use the below as JSON Path expressions and Match No to `-1`:

```
.item[?(@.name=='Test Name' && @.capital=='Capital' && @.region=='NF' && @.subregion=='LoadTesting')].id
```

[image]

You will get below results:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't use JavaScript in the JSR223 Test Elements and [don't use anything but Groovy there](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). Be aware that in JMeter's JSR223 Test Elements you don't have fancy [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) object as it's not a part of [Nashorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) engine so your approach will not work in any case.

The relevant Groovy code to print `items` attribute value to the jmeter.log file would be something like:

```
def items = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).item
def countryDetails = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(items).toPrettyString()
log.info(countryDetails)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and Producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)